# Reason for continuation when examiner opines no improvement on prior art exist

Tags: wo2016085610a1

In reference to the patent: [WO2016085610A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2016085610A1)

The emaminers opinion, ignoring the technical filing error introduced by the occurrence of two mutual exclusive independent claims for which only one examination claim fee was paid, indicated that the group unifying special technical features: “a VTOL aircraft having a first and second wings, and first through fourth variable speed rotors capable of causing the aircraft to take off vertically, transition to a horizontal attitude, and engage in sustained horizontal flight”, as quoted “do not represent a contribution to prior art, because they are anticipated by US20050178879 A1 to Mao (hereinafter 'Mao')”, appears to indicate that it is the opinion of the patent examiners that, anticipating remedy to the existence of dual mutually exclusive independent claims, the application would not even then so represent an improvement upon prior art and therefore there exist no grounds for the granting of a patent in the eventuality.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't quite work out what your question is. Would it be possible to make it a little clearer? As an aside though, examiners often say things which are incorrect: their views are not definitive.

Comment: I have analyzed the examiners opinions myself thoroughly. Both the USPTO and PCT examiners come to the same conclusion and their opinions are correct. The question is, why would the claimants legal representative continue to pursue the application when it appears highly likely that from the onset, they knew full well that no improvements upon prior art, were introduced? In other words, why file a worthless claim knowingly?

Comment: https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/docservicepdf_pct/id00000033588652/WOSA/WO2016085610.pdf

(There are as you know no direct link to the USPTO document below)
http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair
14/554,892  HIGH SPEED MULTI-ROTOR VERTICAL TAKEOFF AND LANDING AIRCRAFT 
05-06-2016  CTNF  Non-Final Rejection